# LLDB can't set breakpoint in reverse engineering

Tags: reverse-engineering, lldb

I'm new to reverse engineering, I want to use LLDB debug other people's app. I have used class-dump and know there is class named *SecurityPlugin*, and has a method name *hashData:* . So I want to set break point at this method, but LLDB prompted me : `WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.`, can somebody tell me how to set the breakpoint, thanks

Comment: If this can be useful to someone, I just had trouble setting breakpoints in LLDB despite compiling with `-g` flag because I was stripping the binaries at link time with `-s`.